# Drag Drop delegate for NSView could not set an attribute

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview, nsdragginginfo

I am using NSView delegate to read the dragged excel values. For this I have subclassed NSView. My code is like-

```
@interface SSDragDropView : NSView
    {
        NSString *textToDisplay;
    }
    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *textToDisplay; // setters/getters

    @synthesize textToDisplay;// setters/getters

    @implementation SSDragDropView
    - (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
        [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
        return NSDragOperationGeneric;
    }

    - (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
        [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
    }

    - (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
        [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
        return YES;
    }


   - (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender {
        NSArray *draggedFilenames = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        if ([[[draggedFilenames objectAtIndex:0] pathExtension] isEqual:@"xls"]){
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    - (void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
        NSArray *draggedFilenames = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        NSURL *url =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[draggedFilenames objectAtIndex:0]];
       NSString *textDataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil]; //This text is the original excel text and its getting displayed.
    [self setTextToDisplay:textDataFile];
       }
```

I am setting the textDataFile value to a string attribute of that class. Now I am using SSDragDropView attribute value in some other class like-

```
SSDragDropView *dragView = [SSDragDropView new];
    NSLog(@"DragView Value is %@",[dragView textToDisplay]);
```

But I am getting null each time. Is it like I can not set an attribute value in those delegate methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem can be resolved just by declaring a global variable in your SSDragDropView.h class.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
NSString *myTextToDisplay;
@interface SSDragDropView : NSView
{
```

The same can be set inside the desired delegate method

```
- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {

// .... //Your Code
NSString *textDataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
myTextToDisplay = textDataFile;
// .... //Your Code
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[dragView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];  

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray *paths = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    NSLog(@"%@",paths);
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
    return NSDragOperationGeneric;
}
```

Below code   will print nil because you are not dragging anything on NSView.

```
SSDragDropView *dragView = [SSDragDropView new];
    NSLog(@"DragView Value is %@",[dragView textToDisplay]);
```

Comment: Hi Parag, I have modified the delegate : draggingEntered.. also added the mentioned code in another class when I was accessing the "textToDisplay" attribute, but still I am getting null.

Comment: Take a look at (sample project) [https://www.dropbox.com/s/6r1a7di07ryi54b/Untitled.zip?v=1mci]

Comment: Hi Parag, The text is getting displayed in that SSDragDropView - in th e delegate--(void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
 ...............sth here
 NSString *textDataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil]; 
    [self setTextToDisplay:textDataFile];
    NSLog(@"textData is %@",textDataFile);// This is displayed
} But My requirement is accessing that textString in some other class(say in AppDelegate) by creating an object of SSDragDropView. Currently that value is returning null.

Comment: I added a button on the xib file and an action in AppDelegate --(IBAction)data:(id)sender
{
    SSDragDropView *dragView = [[SSDragDropView alloc] init];
    [dragView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    NSLog(@"DragView Value is %@",[dragView textToDisplay]);// returns null 
    
}

Comment: It will return nil because there is no text to display.

Comment: How can I get the string value in other class ?

Comment: add another property in your SSDragDropView class. property(assign) id delegate; Now [dragView setDelegate:self]; from concludeDragOperation method call one method [delegate getOutput: textDataFile]; Implement getOutput in your AppDelegate class.

Comment: I have added @property(assign) id delegate; and synthesized it. In SSDragDropView -(void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
----//sth here
    [self setTextToDisplay:textDataFile];
    NSLog(@"textData is %@",textDataFile);
    [delegate getOutput: textDataFile]; 
}
-(void)getOutput:(NSString*)str{
    [delegate setTextToDisplay:str];
} And in AppDelegate I am using like-
    [dragView setDelegate:self];
    [dragView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    NSLog(@"Val %@",[[dragView delegate] textToDisplay]);..Am I missing something?

Comment: -(void)getOutput:(NSString*)output {NSLog(@"%@", output);} Implement this in your appdelegate

Comment: still not getting :( Can u plz make changes to your dropbox project.[dropbox.com/s/6r1a7di07ryi54b/Untitled.zip?v=1mci]